# MockMvc Spring boot rest call Status expected:<200> but was:<500>

Tags: junit5, spring-boot-test

While I am trying to test the get request by MockMvc, I am getting status code as 500 instead of 200.

My Controller class Is :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return productService.getProductList();
    }
}
```

My Test class Is :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ProductController.class, ProductService.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get Product List REST API ")
    void getProductList() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result =
        mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/product/all") 
        .contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();


        String resultDOW = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        assertNotNull(resultDOW);
    }
}
```

When I run test case I got An error java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>

Comment: you have any strack trace there?

Comment: stack trace  ::    java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:98)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
 at com.tcs.ProductControllerTest.getProductList(ProductControllerTest.java:64)

Comment: you need to get to the actual error that causes the 500.. not the assertion error. and put it in the post please

Comment: While running the service as spring boot application. I am able to access the URL with result

Answer (score 1):

Your test failed because in the SpringBootTest configuration is absent a proper HttpMessageConverter, and maybe something else...

I think the right way to do what you want is the using of WebMvcTest:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApiTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    void someApiTest() {

    }

}
```

So, all that you need to test the MVC level is collected by the `@WebMvcTest` annotation, which guarantees the right context configuration for this purpose.